# IOError when trying to send email in Django app

Tags: django

I have a Django app running on a server with uWSGI and nginx.

In my `local_settings.py` file I have this:

```
###############
# EMAIL SETUP #
###############
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY EMAIL PASSWORD'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


########################
# OTHER EMAIL SETTINGS #
########################
ADMIN_EMAIL = "admin@mydomain.com"
SUPPORT_EMAIL = "support@mydomain.com"
```

When I fill out the `/password_reset/` template with an email and submit the form, the email I enter gets no email.

I see these lines in my `uwsgi.log` file after I submit the password reset form.

```
Fri May 11 17:48:10 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /password_reset/ (ip 73.49.35.42) !!!
Fri May 11 17:48:10 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during POST /password_reset/ (73.49.35.42)
IOError: write error
```

What error is this? Why won't the password reset email send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the port number to 465 got rid of the error.